# Python GUI with Checkboxes

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, tkinter, python-3.5

I have been struggling with this problem over the past week and need some help.  I am trying to write a GUI to calculate a total of all the checkboxes selected.  Here is my code so far:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class Joes_auto:

    def __init__(self):

        # Create the main window.
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        # Create the frames.  One for the checkbuttons,
        # one for the total frame, and one for the buttons
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #Create the IntVar objects to use with the checkbuttons
        self.oil_change = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.lube_job = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.radiator_flush = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.transmission_flush = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.inspection = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.muffler_replacement = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.tire_rotation = tkinter.IntVar()

        # Set the IntVar objects to 0
        self.oil_change.set(0)
        self.lube_job.set(0)
        self.radiator_flush.set(0)
        self.transmission_flush.set(0)
        self.inspection.set(0)
        self.muffler_replacement.set(0)
        self.tire_rotation.set(0)

        # Create the Checkbutton widgets in the top_frame
        self.oil_change = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Oil Change ($30)', \
                                                variable=self.oil_change)
        self.lube_job = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Lube Job ($20)', \
                                            variable=self.lube_job)
        self.radiator_flush = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Radiator Flush ($40)', \
                                          variable=self.radiator_flush)
        self.transmission_flush = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Transmission Flush ($100)', \
                                              variable=self.transmission_flush)
        self.inspection = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Inspection ($35)', \
                                      variable=self.inspection)
        self.muffler_replacement = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Muffler Replacement ($200)', \
                                               variable=self.muffler_replacement)
        self.tire_rotation = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Tire Rotation ($20)', \
                                         variable=self.tire_rotation)

        # Pack the Checkbuttons
        self.oil_change.pack()
        self.lube_job.pack()
        self.radiator_flush.pack()
        self.transmission_flush.pack()
        self.inspection.pack()
        self.muffler_replacement.pack()
        self.tire_rotation.pack()

        # Create a total and quit button
        self.total_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'Calculate Total', \
                                           command = self.total)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'Quit', \
                                           command = self.main_window.destroy)

        # Pack the buttons
        self.total_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'left')

        # Pack the frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        # Start the mainloop
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def total(self):

        self.total = 0

        if self.oil_change.get() == 1:
            self.total += 30
        if self.lube_job.get() == 1:
            self.total += 20
        if self.radiator_flush.get() == 1:
            self.total += 40
        if self.transmission_flush.get() == 1:
            self.total += 100
        if self.inspection.get() == 1:
            self.total += 35
        if self.muffler_replacement.get() == 1:
            self.total += 200
        if self.tire_rotation.get() == 1:
            self.total += 20

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Your total is", self.total)

joes_auto = Joes_auto()
```

Every time I run the program I get the AttributeError: Checkbutton has no attribute 'get'.  I want the program to calculate the total of all the services checked and display the total.

Comment: The problem is that you set `self.oil_change = tkinter.IntVar()` to be an `IntVar` (which is fine) but later you overwrite it `self.oil_change = tkinter.Checkbutton(..)`. From that point on `self.oil_change`will not be an `IntVar` anymore but the reference to the Checkbutton. The Checkbutton itself does not have a `get()` method. Solution: Use different variable names for `IntVar` and `Checkbox` objects.

Answer (score 1):

First you create a bunch of `IntVar`s and save them as attributes of your `Joes_auto` instance with

```
self.oil_change = tkinter.IntVar()
```

etc, but then you clobber those attributes with

```
self.oil_change = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Oil Change ($30)', \
                                                variable=self.oil_change)
```

etc. So now `self.oil_change` refers to the Checkbutton, not to the IntVar. And that's why you're getting that error: the IntVar has a `.get` method, but the Checkbutton widget doesn't.

So you need to give your Checkbuttons different names than their associated IntVars. Or don't even bother giving them permanent names, just do

```
b = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Oil Change ($30)',
                                        variable=self.oil_change)
b.pack()
b = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Lube Job ($20)',
                                    variable=self.lube_job)
b.pack()
```

etc. (I got rid of those backslashes - you don't need them there since you're continuing a line within parentheses. That also works inside brackets and braces).

---

BTW, you can save a bit of typing by changing

```
import tkinter
```

to

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Then you can do

```
b = tk.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Oil Change ($30)', variable=self.oil_change)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating `Checkbutton` instances, you're overwriting `IntVar` variables with same names.

```
self.oil_change = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text = 'Oil Change ($30)',
                                      variable=self.oil_change)
```

Avoid that by choosing other name for `Checkbutton` instances. Actually, there's no use case of checkbox instance references; you can pack immediately without saving to variables:

```
# Create the Checkbutton widgets in the top_frame
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Oil Change ($30)',
                    variable=self.oil_change).pack()
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Lube Job ($20)',
                    variable=self.lube_job).pack()
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Radiator Flush ($40)',
                    variable=self.radiator_flush).pack()
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Transmission Flush ($100)',
                    variable=self.transmission_flush).pack()
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Inspection ($35)',
                    variable=self.inspection).pack()
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Muffler Replacement ($200)',
                    variable=self.muffler_replacement).pack()
tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top_frame, text='Tire Rotation ($20)',
                    variable=self.tire_rotation).pack()
```

There's another attribute overwriting issue, in `total` method: The method is overwriting `self.total`; method will be replaced with a `int` object. Because the method is bound, and will not be used outside; so no symptom will arise unless you access `total` method in other place, but still not valid.

I suggest to change `self.total = 0` to `total = 0`, because `total` is used only  in the method.

```
def total(self):
    total = 0

    if self.oil_change.get() == 1:
        total += 30
    if self.lube_job.get() == 1:
        total += 20
    if self.radiator_flush.get() == 1:
        total += 40
    if self.transmission_flush.get() == 1:
        total += 100
    if self.inspection.get() == 1:
        total += 35
    if self.muffler_replacement.get() == 1:
        total += 200
    if self.tire_rotation.get() == 1:
        total += 20

    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Your total is", total)
```